# Key Value Observing on an NSView object...or just in general

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

So, moving a rectangle across an `NSView` object, sometimes the object moves exactly like I want, other times the only way to make the rectangle move is by redrawing the view by minimizing or maximizing the window.

I have a `WorldObject` that holds X and Y properties. The `WorldObject` is created in `WorldController` and initiated in `WorldController's awakefromNIB` call. There also begins a timer, which calls a `WorldObject` move method which simply increments the X property every so many fractions of a second.

My drawing is done in a subclass of NSView `DTWViewObject`. This subclass links to `WorldController` through an IBOutlet so that I can:

**1**. call `self.WorldController.WorldObject addObserver:ForKeyPath` with the observer being DTWViewObject and the keypath being @"X" and

**2**. access `WorldController.WorldObject's` X and Y properties for drawing within my drawing code. Then I have a `ObserveValueForKeyPath` method in `DTWViewObject` to parse my KVO and call `setNeedsDisplay` so that my drawing code will redraw the screen with the rectangle at its new "X" position whenever the observee's X property changes.

The problem is, only sometimes it works. Sometimes the object's X property is incremented, but the display is never redrawn, and I've narrowed THAT down to the `ObserveValueForKeyPath` method is not being called on seemingly random builds. Is there a way to further diagnose this?

Comment: Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We will be better able to help you if, instead of just describing your code, you include your actual code. Edit your question to include the code of the method that creates your timer, the code of the method that the timer calls, and the code of your `observeValueForKeyPath:` method. Copy and paste the code. Don't retype it or summarize it, because that often leaves out important details or introduces extra mistakes.

Comment: I will try to include more of that next time. I did solve my problem by replacing Key Value Observing, with NSNotificationCenter methods. Now the code works flawlessly every build. Im still not entirely sure why it did not work every time with KVO. It seems like my observer, on SOME builds, would not register as an observer, while on other builds it did just fine.